# How to make function with two different parameters taken from the lists?

Tags: python, list, function

Well, I wrote this function:

```
def hydrostatic_pressure(altitude, density, number_stages, direction):
    i=0
    hydro_pressure=[]
    print(number_stages)
    while i < number_stages:
        if direction[i] == True:    # направление вверх от РО
            hydro_pressure[i]=density*altitude[i]*9.8 # 9.8 - g, константа

        else:
            hydro_pressure[i]=-1*density*altitude[i]*9.8 # вниз от РО
        i +=1
    return hydro_pressure
```

and this is a function call:

```
list_hydrostat=hydrostatic_pressure(*scheme[4][5][2], enviroment[2], scheme[4][5][3], *scheme[4][5][1])
```

Where:
*scheme[4][5][2] and *scheme[4][5][1] - list including variable number of elements

I got this error:

```
TypeError: hydrostatic_pressure() takes 4 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

So, how to make a correct call?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using the `*` operator there. If they are lists, and the function is expecting lists for those parameters, just pass them as is.

Answer (score 0):

Like **Daniel Roseman** said, `*` operator is not required. And also I have mistake in line `hydro_pressure[i]=density*altitude[i]*9.8`, because hydro_pressure is a empty list without indexes. It is necessary to use generator  `hydro_pressure = [i*0 for i in range(0, len(direction))]` (direction is a list)